# Add sub claim to access token in AD FS server 2019

Tags: active-directory, adfs

I'm trying to figure out how to add the `sub` claim the the access token issued by AD FS server 2019. It is not included when I look at the contents of the token.

The goal is to have a unique ID per user we can use when storing values in our database.

Does anyone know how to configure AD FS server 2019 to add the `sub` claim to the issued access token? According to the documentation for Azure AD, it should be there, but this is AD FS on premise.

I've seen [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/564959/send-objectguid-as-an-ad-fs-2-0-claim), but I am not sure if the `PPID` is the correct value to add.
There's also [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/564959/send-objectguid-as-an-ad-fs-2-0-claim), which mentions `objectGUID`. But, according to the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/overview/ad-fs-faq), the `sub` claim is:

> The value of “sub” claim is the hash of client ID + anchor claim
>   value.

Since the `sub` is a compound value, I'd like for AD to give it to me.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @domiSchenk Unfourtunately, I don't remember anymore :(